# Probability of every coin displaying HEAD if a coin is tossed 12 times

Tags: probability

What is the probability of every coin displaying HEAD if a coin is tossed 12 times. Is it $\frac{1}{12}$ or $\frac{1}{1024}$?

Comment: Why do you think either of those two numbers is the answer?

Comment: Okay ..Actually i have 3 options in test paper .last 1 was none of them .Can u solve the query

Comment: In any case, do you want the probability of every toss resulting in heads or at least one toss resulting in heads, or something in between?

Comment: every toss resulting in heads o

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a coin tossed for 3 times what is the probability of getting all tails?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185964/if-a-coin-tossed-for-3-times-what-is-the-probability-of-getting-all-tails)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** What is the probability of one toss resulting in heads? How do you compute the probability of success in two *independent* events? How about twelve?

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* The propbability of $n$ independant events each having probability $p$ occuring is $p^n$.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. The probability of 1 head appearing in 12 tosses is certainly not $\frac{1}{2^{12}}$.

Comment: Yes i think u r right

Comment: @DonLarynx, actually, it does, see OP's comments to the question.

Comment: Ah okay. My apologies.

Comment: And so the probability of *any* specified sequence of outcomes in tossing a fair coin 12 times is $1/2^{12}$. Nothing special about all HEADS.