# If a coin tossed for $3$ times what is the probability of getting all tails?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If a coin tossed for $3$ times what is the probability of getting all tails?

Is  $\frac{1}{8}$ the right answer?

Comment: For future reference, please include your work, not just the final numerical value. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You will benefit from the following article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

If the coin is fair, then the odds of getting heads or tails should be equal, $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then 3 tosses of tails will have a chance of $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac18$.

Answer (score 3):

Tossing of the coin is an independent event. The probablility of each event is $\frac{1}{2}.$ Hence, the desired probability is $$\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, the right answer is 1/4

The reasoning towards this is that tossing the coin three times could give the following combinations:

H = Heads

T = Tails

T , T , T

T , T , H

T , H , T

T , H , H

H , H , H

H , H , T

H , T , H

H , T , T

Total Combinations = 8

3 Consecutive Tails/Heads = 2

Answer = 2/8 = 1/4

Comment: The querrant asked for the probability for getting all *tails* not for all *the same*.